# Unit testing with header-only dependencies

Tags: c++, unit-testing

Given a module which `#include`s some bloated headers with in-place definitions (like a header-only library), it's not quite easy to stub/mock/spy the dependencies from them.

I can see only one way: for each such header create its fake counterpart with only the definitions the module actually uses, and run each test with it's own compiler configuration where the include path's point to the fakes.

Am I missing something, is there a better way?

Comment: Well you can create a complete set of generic mocks/stubs rather than have multiple versions of each header, but otherwise ... yes, that's essentially right. Unless the code you're testing is _also_ header-only, in which case there's an easier way ...

Comment: You might want to restructure the "bloated header", by extracting relevant parts to separate headers which can be tested separately.  If you're not responsible for it (e.g. a tester independent of the development team), push for the developers to do that.    The business case justification is that it will cost less - in the long run, if not immediately - to restructure the code to facilitate unit testing than it will to keep updating the unit testing to cope with the bloated header.